# Adobe DTM - Analytics/Omniture query string missing parameters

Tags: adobe-analytics

I've searched for days looking into this issue but have yet to come up with something. We are migrating our analytics code over to DTM. We are using our own Library hosted at DTM. Everything works great except for some missing data collection parameters in the query string only when using the Adobe Analytics tool to assign variables.

Let me explain. When I use custom code in DTM in a rule to call analytics I get exactly the same query string parameters in the request that we were getting before.

```
var str = 'string';
s.linkTrackVars = 'prop61,eVar61';
s.linkTrackEvents = 'none';
s.prop61 = str;
s.eVar61 = str;
s.tl(this, 'o', str);
```

This works fine.

If I try to set eVar61 and prop61 with the Adobe Analytics tool inside a rule, five parameters are no longer in the query string. Specifically 'pev1', 'pid', 'pidt', 'oid' and 'ot'. Is there a way to get DTM to set those parameters or am I just to use custom code for all our rules?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your current rule setup? An event based rule, with Adobe Analytics set to fire a s.tl call on an `a` element will fire those parameters.

Comment: We are using an Event Based Rule with "s.tl(); - does NOT increment a pageview" selected. In the eVars settings: eVar61="string" and in the Props settings: prop61="string". We get none of 'pev1', 'pid', 'pidt', 'oid' and 'ot' parameters in the query string.

Comment: What is the selector/condition set to? Those parameters are mainly for clickmap

Comment: The selector is targeting an anchor tag and there are no conditions.

Comment: ..Event Type is click.

Answer (score 1):

Those are clickmap query string parameters. Click on the gear icon to edit the global Analytics tool, and under Link Tracking, make sure 'Enable Clickmap' is checked. Alternatively, you can set `s.trackInlineStats=true` in your code, which effectively achieves the same effect.

If you ever see missing query string parameters in the future, you can determine what variables to define using the [Data Collection Query Parameters](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/query_parameters.html) in the Marketing Cloud documentation.

Comment: Yes, that was it exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct in case others have the same problem in the future.